# Clicking more than one time of 'Read more' button in modal frame Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog, selenium-chromedriver, click

I want to get all reviews of guests. But there are reviews which have long text that use to click 'read more' button to see all texts. The problem is the number of buttons is depend on reviews. I can load and get all reviews it's work fine but I have no idea with 'read more' button. How to click all 'read more' button in modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7KGM.png)

Link URL: https://th.airbnb.com/rooms/27194960/reviews?source_impression_id=p3_1600195106_a%2FYGw9bddHf%2BMfUE

The code below is a function to get HTML text from URL. There are 2 conditions which we will focus on condition 2 which gets reviews you can see in if-else condition --- if review:.

```py
def get_pageswithSelenium(roomid,review,page_send):
    #session = requests.Session()
    #ua = UserAgent()
    #headers = {'User-Agent':ua.random}  
    if not(review):
        url = "https://th.airbnb.com/rooms/{}?source_impression_id=p3_1600195106_a%2FYGw9bddHf%2BMfUE".format(roomid)
    else:
        url = "https://th.airbnb.com/rooms/{}/reviews?source_impression_id=p3_1600195106_a%2FYGw9bddHf%2BMfUE".format(roomid)
    print("selenium url: "+url)
    
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get(url)
    
    if review:
        browser.implicitly_wait(20)
        element_inside_popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_yzu7qn"]//a')
        for j in range(page_send):
            element_inside_popup.send_keys(Keys.END)
            time.sleep(5)
            print(str(j))
            #find all 'read more' button and click (code here)
    else:
        browser.implicitly_wait(12)
    
    html = browser.page_source

    bsObj_bd = BeautifulSoup(html,'html')
    return bsObj_bd
```

I use Selenium with a Chrome driver. Thanks, everyone to come and help in advance.

Comment: You need to provide a link of the actual page you need to scrape, otherwise it would be very difficult to provide any help.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for coming to help! i put a link in the post already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the 'read more' button exists using `wait` and `try-except`.

See [this link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more info about `wait`.

```py
#find all 'read more' button and click (code here)

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_yzu7qn']//button[@class='_ejra3kg']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("no read more")
else:
    for button in buttons:
        button.click()
```

Comment: @SunsithornTuntipong Please accept and up vote if it solved your problem, it will help others and myself in turn.

Comment: Oh, im really sorry. i already accept and up vote. Thanks.